# Lyndon basis of free Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, free-lie-algebras, lyndon-words

Let $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$ be a set of totally ordered alphabets, a Lyndon word over $A$ is a word $w$ in $A^*$ such that if $w=uv$ is a factorization of $w$ into non-empty subwords, then $u<v$ in lexicographic order. This is equivalent to being the unique minimum word (in lexicographic order) among all its rotations.

Let $\mathcal{L}(A)$ be the free Lie algebra on the set $A$. It is well known that [Lyndon words in $A$ indexes a basis for $\mathcal(L)(A)$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lie_algebra#Lyndon_basis)

Assume $a$ is the least alphabet and let $w=a_1a_2\cdots a_k \in A^*$ (free monoid over $A$) define $L(w) = [a_1,[a_2,[\cdots[a_{k-1},a_k]\cdots]$ to be the right associative Lie monomial associated to $w$ in $\mathcal{L}(A)$. 
 By rotation, I always mean another word $w^{'}$ which is obtained from $w$ by rotating the alphabets cyclically and further we also want this word to start with $a$.

Let $w = abcad$ and let $w^{'}=adabc$ be a rotation of $w$.
My question is $L(w)$ and $L(w^{'})$ are linearly dependent as Lyndon words indexes a basis and $w$ and $w^{'}$ are rotationally equivalent.

More generally, I want to understand the linear dependence relation between the Lie monomials $L(w),L(w_1),\dots,L(w_k)$ where $w,w_1,w_2,\dots,w_k$ are all possible rotations of $w$ in the above sense.

How to understand the linear dependence relation between general right-associative Lie monomials and what makes the Lyndon words the indexing set for the basis of free Lie algebras? How the rotation of words affects the Lyndon words.

Kindly share your thoughts.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. But $\left[a,\left[b,\left[c,d\right]\right]\right]$, $\left[b,\left[c,\left[d,a\right]\right]\right]$, $\left[c,\left[d,\left[a,b\right]\right]\right]$ and $\left[d,\left[a,\left[b,c\right]\right]\right]$ are (in general) linearly independent.

Comment: It's been too long since I've thought about this stuff, but I want to recommend the book "Free Lie Algebras" by Christophe Reutenauer.  It was an absolute pleasure to read, and I'm certain that the book has a good discussion of why there is a basis in correspondence with Lyndon words.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Can you please explain to me, how those monomials are linearly independent? I have edited the question, kindly reconsider this. Thank you.

Comment: Not much to explain -- just compute them in the free Lie algebra and check that there is no nontrivial relation. I did it with SageMath and https://github.com/darijgr/sage-subspace .

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks for the code. It is very nice. Everything has been worked out for free Lie algebras. Can you please tell me how to check the linear dependence of $\left[a,\left[b, \left[c,d\right]\right]\right]$,$\left[b,\left[c,\left[d,a\right]\right]\right]$,$\left[c,\left[d,\left[a,b\right]\right]\right]$ and $\left[d,\left[a,\left[b,c\right]\right]\right]$  if we impose some commutation relations among the generators $a,b,c$ and $d$ using this sage codes?. Thank you.

Comment: The sage-subspace code works in any algebra, as long as you know a basis of said algebra. I have used the free algebra, since it is the universal enveloping algebra of the free Lie algebra. If I imposed some commutativity relations, I'd need more subtle algebras, which Sage may or may not have. Feel free to experiment with any sufficiently up-to-date version of Sage (the development ones from 2020 should work).